# Send inline image in body email with IsBodyHtml = false in C#

Tags: c#, image, email, inline

I need to send an inline image in an email body in C#.
I'm using this to get the image:

```
Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
inline.ContentId = "MyImage";
inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath);
```

I've seen a solution building an HTML body and adding the image by

```
<img src=\"cid:MyImage\" alt=\"\" />
```

But, **is there any way to make it with IsBodyHtml = false?**

The whole application is working like that, just assigning strings to the body, and it can be a lot of time changing all the existing bodies to fit the HTML.

Comment: If the body is not html, then it is plain text. And plain text cannot contain markup or images

Comment: Thanks, I'll make everything html then!

Comment: Another way of inserting an image is converting the image to base4 text and make the img src from that text